# Bridge WiFi adapter with Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge

We have Wireless network in our unit that is connected to VOIP network of building.

All PC's and laptops connect wireless to unit's access point.

The problem is connecting Wired SIP phone to wireless network of unit by bridging PC's Wifi connection.

For this goal we check different configurations and all failed except one config.

Success of solutions: in-range IP config of SIP phone.

Solutions failed: wireless adapter connected to AP and LAN connected to SIP phone. Bridge this two network adapter. SIP phone has not received any IP.

Laptop-1: (Lenovo t450s, Windows 10 64bits)

PC-1(Asus H110 plus + TP link WN722N usb wifi adapter)

PC-2(Asus H110 plus + Tenda W311Ma usb Wifi adapter)

Solution that succeed:
Laptop-2: (HP elitebook 2540p) wireless adapter connected to AP and LAN connected to SIP phone. Bridge this two network adapter. SIP phone receive valid and in range ip address.

What is the problem with most configurations and how to troubleshoot SIP phone that can't get IP in this situations?
Is there any special ability in network cards?

Note: I have tested internet connections sharing feature, it is not suitable because of NAT and different IP range of shared network, so SIP phone will get local IP but not in range.

Comment: Configuration issues aside, this solution will not provide you very good voice quality on your sip phones.

Comment: The problem is likely that your bridges (the wifi adaptors) aren't passing broadcasts over.

Comment: @djsmiley2k seems true, how to handle it?

Comment: That's a FAQ: You can't bridge a WLAN STA to a LAN interface, unless the WLAN (and **all** devices on it) use 4-address mode. (You can bridge a WLAN AP, though). You can route, you can remove the intermediate host from the WLAN, you can do this with WLAN interfaces that allow multiple STAs, but all of this is a crutch. Routing and a SIP proxy would probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: @dirkt sorry but i can't get that, please clarify or share a reference. just for sure did you notice that we have success solution with other laptop?

Comment: I noticed, and I suspect it's a WLAN interface with multiple STAs, which would explain why it works on this laptop on not on the others. And I'm sure it can't work in principle, because the protocols are the way they are. I know, because I tried to get this to work years ago. I'll see if I can dig up a good reference.

Comment: A [reference](https://serverfault.com/a/114666) that at least states that it doesn't work, and the question goes a bit into why it doesn't work. Sorry, couldn't find a better one yet.

Comment: What kind of solutions are you open to? New hardware? A dd-wrt router could do the conversion from the AP to Ethernet in wireless bridge mode. But I must say, this is bad practice for voice. Why not just use csipsimple, or another soft-phone if your using wireless. At the very least, you should have QOS setup on the wireless interface if any other clients are passing bulk data. (Really any other data than sip/rtp!) Voip is very difficult to get working properly in a CSMA/CD network. VLANs are recommended

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It is fine to add inexpensive hardware. I haven't think of using soft-phone, thanks for useful advises

Comment: @dirkt thanks, I got that it dose not going to work this way, so the answer would be there is no (Simple) way to bridge wireless connection to Ethernet

Comment: @Behnam Heydari, look into dd-wrt. Either buy a dd-wrt compatible router. Or go with a wireless bridge.